# weakest topology and strongest topology

Tags: general-topology, continuity

A topology $\tau$ is stronger than a topology σ (is a finer topology) if τ contains all the open sets of σ.

> let $f:(X,\tau_1) \to (Y,\tau_2)$ be onto map and for every $V\subseteq Y$ , $f^{-1}(V)$ is open iff $V$ be open. now which of following options are true ?

1-$\tau_1$ is weakest topology on $X$ such that $f$ is continuous.

2- $\tau_1$ is strongest topology on $X$ such that $f$ is continuous.

3-$\tau_2$ is weakest topology on $Y$ such that $f$ is continuous.

4-$\tau_2$ is strongest topology on $Y$ such that $f$ is continuous.

> let $X=Y=[0,1]$ and $f$ be identity map and  $\tau_2=\tau_1$ is euclidean topology . so "2" is wrong because $\tau_1\subset \tau_{discrete}$ ? also "3" is wrong because $\tau_{indiscrete } \subset \tau_2$.now let $X=[0,1]$ and $\tau_1$ be  euclidean topology , $Y=\{p\}$ with $\tau_2=\{ \emptyset , \{p\}\}$and $f(x)=p$ then $\tau_{indiscrete } \subset \tau_1  $ so "1" is wrong .then "4" is true ?

Comment: Here's [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)

Comment: @BrianMoehring . let $X=\mathbb{N}$ and $Y=\{1,2\} $ and $f(1)=f(3)=f(5)=...=f(2k+1)=1$ and $f(2)=f(4)=f(6)=...=f(2k)=2$ so $f$ is onto .now let $\tau_2 =\{ \emptyset , Y \}$ and $\tau_1 =\{ \emptyset , X , \{2,4,6,...\},\{ 1,3,5,...\} \}$ now options "1" and "2" are false .

Comment: @1200785626 That example also doesn't satisfy the conditions in the problem.  It works if you instead set $\tau_2 = \{\emptyset, \{1\}, \{2\}, Y\}$.  Once you have such an example, though, showing e.g. option 1 is false would require finding another topology on $X$ weaker than $\tau_1$ under which $f$ is continuous.  For your choice of $\tau_1$, however, no such topology exists, so we cannot conclude from this that option 1 is false.

Comment: Here are some hints: First consider the identity map on $[0,1]$ with the Euclidean topology.  Then consider a constant map $X \to \{p\}$.  Between the two of these, you will be able to eliminate three of the four answers.  Then prove that the last remaining answer is true.

Comment: @BrianMoehring . But constant map is not onto .

Comment: @BrianMoehring. If we consider identity map on [0,1] then discrate  topology is strnger than euclidean topology on $X$ so 2 is wrong?

Comment: @BrianMoehring .i edited my question .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The examples at the end show that options 1, 2, 3 are false.

To see 4 is true, first note that by the given property, $f : (X,\tau_1) \to (Y,\tau_2)$ is continuous.  Then, let $\tau_3$ denote a topology on $Y$ such that $f : (X,\tau_1) \to (Y,\tau_3)$ is continuous.  Then given $V \in \tau_3$, we have $f^{-1}(V) \in \tau_1$, and by the property given in the problem, $V \in \tau_2$.  Therefore $\tau_3 \subseteq \tau_2$, which shows 4 is true.